# scatter chart is not rendering properly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fusioncharts

I'm using fusioncharts library. I am not able to find what's wrong with data which I'm sending for `scatter` chart.

Demo - [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6deM9/72/)

```
{
    "chart": {
        "animation": 0,
        "yaxisname": "OAE (%)",
        "xaxisname": "Week",
        "xaxismaxvalue": 54,
        "xaxisminvalue": 0,
        "showregressionline": "1",
        "regressionlinethickness": "2",
        "regressionLineColor": "008ee4",
        "bgcolor": "FFFFFF",
        "canvasborderthickness": "1",
        "canvasbordercolor": "CCCCCC",
        "showalternatehgridcolor": "0",
        "divlineColor": "#FFFFFF",
        "showLegend": "1",
        "showValues": "1"
    },
    "categories": [{
        "verticallinecolor": "c7c7c7",
        "category": [{
            "label": "46",
            "x": "46",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "47",
            "x": "47",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "48",
            "x": "48",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "49",
            "x": "49",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "50",
            "x": "50",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "51",
            "x": "51",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "52",
            "x": "52",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "53",
            "x": "53",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "01",
            "x": "01",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "02",
            "x": "02",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "03",
            "x": "03",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }, {
            "label": "04",
            "x": "04",
            "showverticalline": "1"
        }]
    }],
    "dataset": [{
        "seriesname": "Target",
        "color": "93cc1a",
        "regressionLineColor": "93cc1a",
        "showValues": "0",
        "anchorradius": "0",
        "anchorSides": "8",
        "regressionLineThickness": "5",
        "anchorBorderColor": "2A612D",
        "anchorBgColor": "93cc1a",
        "data": [{
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "46"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "47"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "48"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "49"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "50"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "51"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "52"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "53"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "01"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "02"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "03"
        }, {
            "y": "40%",
            "x": "04"
        }]
    }, {
        "seriesname": "OAE",
        "color": "008ee4",
        "anchorradius": "5",
        "anchorSides": "7",
        "anchorBorderColor": "008ee4",
        "anchorBgColor": "008ee4",
        "data": [{
            "y": "29.73",
            "x": "46"
        }, {
            "y": "100.36",
            "x": "47"
        }, {
            "y": "69.37",
            "x": "48"
        }, {
            "y": "55.55",
            "x": "49"
        }, {
            "y": "64.4",
            "x": "50"
        }, {
            "y": "135.43",
            "x": "51"
        }, {
            "y": "55.02",
            "x": "52"
        }, {
            "y": "NA",
            "x": "53"
        }, {
            "y": "NA",
            "x": "01"
        }, {
            "y": "73.36",
            "x": "02"
        }, {
            "y": "8.28",
            "x": "03"
        }, {
            "y": "137.91",
            "x": "04"
        }],
        "dashed": "1"
    }]
}
```

You can see there are space in between the chart X-axis. Also I want that chart should plot X-axis as I'm passing in categories object. Why it's automatically sorted.

Answer (score 0):

In the fiddle, if you check the minimum value for x-axis ranges from 01-04 and max values from 46 to 52.

Since, there isn't any labels in between 04 and 46, the space in-between is empty. The chart actually is plotted from 01 to 52, the space in between where there is no value or labels will not be skipped.

You can achieve what you want using `label`.  Its just a work around.

[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6deM9/75/)

```
"categories": [{
   "verticallinecolor": "c7c7c7",
      "category": [{
         "label": "46",
          "x": "0",
          "showverticalline": "1"
       }, {
          "label": "47",
          "x": "1",
          "showverticalline": "1",
       } //......
```